# extract nth authors from excel

Tags: excel, vba, split, reference, extract

How to extract single authors, two authors, three authors and more authors references from one columns (list of references) through vba in excel

```
Walkenbach, J. (2010). Excel 2010 power programming with VBA (Vol. 6). John Wiley & Sons.
Jackson, M., & Staunton, M. (2006). Advanced modelling in finance using Excel and VBA. John Wiley & Sons.
```

for example:

```
single author output: Walkenbach, J. 
two author: Jackson, M., & Staunton, M. 
and etc.
```

```
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20").Cells 
   myarray = Split(c, "(")
```

#and to recognize number of authors based on `myarray(0)` and the number of commas

Comment: Authors = vba.len(myArray(0))-(vba.len(vba.replace(myarray(0),",",vbnullstring)+1)

Comment: Could use a couple more examples with >2 authors...